# why Stack Overflow more crowded and other stack Exchange Q&A sites not?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, review, stack-exchange

I can see the view count and participation of Stack Overflow Questions are much better than other Stack Exchange Q&A sites.

I don't have any statistics to prove it, but when we are in those sites other than SO, we can feel the difference.

And also I have a doubt whether the Stack Exchange family evolved from SO or not?

Comment: *I don't have any statistics to prove it*. You're in for a world of pain, then. Quick, go fetch some statistics, then come back.

Comment: Because StackOverflow was the first one in the network.

Comment: Because programmers have detailed easy to forget knowledge. And programmers are tied to their computer all the time.

Comment: You can find some statistics here: http://stackexchange.com/sites#users

Comment: Stack Overflow is much bigger than the other sites. It came first, and still is the flagship of the fleet.

Comment: Could you clarify your last sentence? It's not clear to me what you're asking there.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi ya here i am mymone, if i doesn't mention about the proof, you guys will ask me about the same thing (experience from previous Q i asked in MSO),So i mentioned it here and you comment about it in this way.
just go through post like this.and also be helpful friend. [Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Stack Overflow was the original site. It predates all of them.

It was also founded by [Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/) and [Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/) both of which were prominent bloggers within the software developer world. This meant that Stack Overflow had high exposure from day 0 - programmers knew about it.

Other sites on the network are both newer and don't have this kind of exposure (can you imagine what would happen to the cooking site if several celebrity chefs blogged about it?), so they tend to have much less traffic.

The result of less traffic - less questions, less answers, answers take longer to be given etc...

> And also have a doubt, Whether the stack exchange family evolved from SO or not?

Well, they all share the same codebase. So Stack Overflow code is the same code that runs the rest of the family of sites. The codebase (and database design) were originally started for Stack Overflow - not for the "family", though it has changed since to cater for them all. Not sure if that answers that question though.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow was the first site created, as it grew popular, other sites were created and each site has its own popularity. Some like programming, and some like music and math.

Since programming requires an internet and a programmer could make a lot of mistakes, SO is a perfect site for developers. However, for math, an internet is not really required so it's as not as popular, but still popular.

Comment: *Since programming requires an internet.* Sonny, I was already programming when the Internet was nearly empty and only available to a few universities half the world away from me, and I'm not alone. Now get off my lawn.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - lol. Those days where you had to read books in order to learn how to program... the dark ages ;)

Comment: Yeah, but we are talking about today. Most smart programmers use resources. Most resources come from the internet.

Comment: Sure. But you can still program without being online.

Comment: I am not disagreeing on that.